# Finding the appropriate interval

Tags: r, algorithm

Suppose I've several intervals which are subset of real line as follows:

```
I_1 = [0, 1]
I_2 = [1.5, 2]
I_3 = [5, 9]
I_4 = [13, 16]
```

Now given a real number `x = 6.4`, say, I'd like to find which interval contains the number `x`. I would like to know the algorithm to find this interval, and/or how to do this in R.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update using non-equi joins:**

This is much simpler and straightforward using the new *non-equi* joins feature in the [current development version of data.table, v1.9.7](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation):

```
require(data.table) # v1.9.7+
DT1 = data.table(start=c(0,1.5,5,1,2,3,4,5), end=c(1,2,9,2,3,4,5,6))

DT1[.(x=4.5), on=.(start<=x, end>=x), which=TRUE]
# [1] 7
```

No need to set keys or create indices.

---

**Old solution using `foverlaps`:**

One way would be to use interval/overlap joins using the `data.table` package:

```
require(data.table) ## 1.9.4+
DT1 = data.table(start=c(0,1.5,5,13), end=c(1,2,9,16))
DT2 = data.table(start=6.4, end=6.4)

setkey(DT1)
foverlaps(DT2, DT1, which=TRUE, type="within")
#    xid yid
# 1:   1   3
```

This searches if each interval in `DT2` lies completely within `DT1` efficiently. In your case `DT2` is a point, not an interval. If it did not exist within any intervals in `DT1`, it'd return `NA`.

Have a look at `?foverlaps` to check out the other arguments you can use. For example `mult=` argument controls if you'd want to return all the matching rows or just the first or last etc..

---

Since `setkey` sorts the result, you'll have to add a separate `id` as follows:

```
DT1 = data.table(start=c(0,1.5,5,1,2,3,4,5), end=c(1,2,9,2,3,4,5,6))
DT1[, id := .I] # .I is a special variable. See ?data.table
setkey(DT1, start, end)

DT2 = data.table(start=4.5 ,end=4.5)
olaps = foverlaps(DT2, DT1, type="within", which=TRUE)

olaps[, yid := DT1$id[yid]]
#    xid yid
# 1:   1   7
```

Comment: @Arun...thanks for your attention. Here is an is an problem of using the above code.                                              > DT1 = data.table(start=c(0,1.5,5,1,2,3,4,5), end=c(1,2,9,2,3,4,5,6))
> DT2 = data.table(start=4.5 ,end=4.5)
> setkey(DT1)
> foverlaps(DT2, DT1, which=TRUE, type="within")
> xid yid
1:   1   5
2:   1 6

Comment: The above answer is is certainly not true...The answer should be 7. But it is giving 5 and 6. I could not find out why it is not working.